# minimum matching distance

Tags: clustering

I'm reading "Clustering Stability: An Overview" by Ulrike von Luxburg, and she mentions the minimum matching distance.

$$d_{MM}(C, C') := \min_π 1/n \sum_1^n 1_{C(X_i)\neq π(C'(X_i))}$$

Where the $\pi$ are permutations of the labelings. I'm having a hard time finding intuitive explanations of this, and I can't wrap my head around it.  Does anyone have a good example of this thing?  It seems to be related to the Hungarian Algorithm, if that rings a bell.

Comment: @Bernhard, good catch.  I am thoroughly embarrassed.

Comment: If I just added a distraction, I am truely sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 1 on 1 map between clusters 1...k and classes a, b, c. They may not even have the same number.

Pi is the optimum mapping, and you can either find this by trying all permutations (horribly slow) or by the Hungarian algorithm (still slow, n³). Or you use one of the better measures that avoids needing such a mapping.

Comment: Ah. So clustering $C$ is applying labels $X_i \rightarrow c_i$, $C'$ is applying labels $X_j \rightarrow d_j$, and $\pi$ is a mapping $d_i \rightarrow c_i$?

Comment: Yes, the pi function is used to consider *all possible* mappings of C labels to D labels.